# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - Django Python

Tags: python, django

Error: *Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (crm3.
plugins_plugins, CONSTRAINT plugins_plugins_category_id_b93592ae_fk_plugins_p FOREIGN KEY
(category_id) REFERENCES plugins_pluginscategory (id)))*

При попытке сделать запись категории, которой нет в связанной модели ForeignKey, выдает ошибку. Как обойти? или чтобы по дефолту выставлялась допустим 1?

**tags.py**

```
def add_plugin_in_db(data):
    plugin = Plugins()
    plugin.title = data['title']
    plugin.category_id = data['category'] # если не правильная категория, крашится
    plugin.save(force_insert=True)
```

**models.py**

```
class Plugins(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Название')    
    category = models.ForeignKey('PluginsCategory', default=1, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='get_category')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class PluginsCategory(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, verbose_name='Наименования категории')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Просто проверить существование категории перед записью?

Comment: проверить существование,  если нет то дефолт

Comment: Ну вот вы и ответили на свой вопрос

Comment: а есть что-то изщное? почему default не отрабатывает в модели?

Comment: Потому что вы собственноручно меняете default на своё значение в строке `plugin.category_id = data['category']` — и корректность указанного значения переходит под вашу личную ответственность

Comment: а есть какая-то магия джанго, чтобы указать категорию? или писать if then итд

Comment: Напишите такую функцию сами и запихните внутрь неё все нужные if then, например?

Comment: Но лично я бы в первую очередь задумался над тем, а какого хрена в `data['category']` каким-то чудом вообще попало некорректное значение

Comment: да, это понятно, но я где-то видел уже под капотом джанго в моделс такое решение, не могу вспомнить, а может и не видел

Comment: data['category'] оно туда прилетает по api и могут отправить нехорошие люди бяку

Comment: Поэтому прилетевшие данные должны строго проверяться на корректность вдоль и поперёк. Если уж вы не используете Django-формы или какой-то ещё инструмент для парсинга/валидации, то хотя бы `plugin.full_clean()` сделайте — он вам в ответ выплюнет `Объект модели plugins category со значением поля id, равным N, не существует` — а уже этого в свою очередь можно отправить обнаглевшему пользователю api чтобы он чинил свой кривой код